# What type should I use to store the ISBN number in C?

Tags: isbn

I'm creating a code which storing the book data into a struct. So, the data including the book's title, author's name, price and ISBN number *(which including the dashes to group the 13-digit code)*. So for title and name, for sure using `string` and also `float` for price. But I'm stuck in ISBN number because it containing dashes. So, what type should I use to store the numbers and dashes? 
I'm still a beginner in coding program. :(

Comment: Use a string for the ISBN number. But do not use float for the price: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: If you're storing dashes, you pretty much have no choice but to store it as a string.  However, I would store it as a `struct {unsigned short EAN; unsigned char group; unsigned short publisher, unsigned short title; unsigned char checkdigit;}`, and use a function to convert to and from strings. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number